# Java/Selenium RemoteWebDriver/Maven/JUnit - Get null session id while trying to invoke browser

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, webdriver

Background/Setup:
I have a bunch of test classes in JUnit. All configured through Maven and Eclipse both. Each test class instantiates a RemoteWebDriver instance and quits it in the tearDown method after the test class has finished executing.

When i try to run all the tests by doing a "mvn clean install", some of the tests execute just fine but the rest of them fail because of the following exception (stacktrace):

```
Tests in error: 
  com.tagged.qa.selenium.tests.gifts.GiftsPageTest: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.(..)
  com.tagged.qa.selenium.tests.tags.TagsPageTest: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.(..)
  addFriendsTest(com.tagged.qa.selenium.tests.friends.FriendsTest): Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.(..)
  deleteFriendsTest(com.tagged.qa.selenium.tests.friends.FriendsTest): Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.(..)
  com.tagged.qa.selenium.tests.statusupdates.StatusUpdatesTest: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.(..)
  com.tagged.qa.selenium.tests.comments.CommentsTest: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.(..)
  com.tagged.qa.selenium.tests.search.SearchPageTest: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.(..)
  com.tagged.qa.selenium.tests.homepage.HomePageTest: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.(..)
  com.tagged.qa.selenium.tests.wink.WinkPageTest: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.(..)
  com.tagged.qa.selenium.tests.profile.ProfilePageTest: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.(..)
  com.tagged.qa.selenium.tests.footerpagestests.TermsOfServiceTest: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.(..)

Tests run: 18, Failures: 0, Errors: 11, Skipped: 0
```

Checking the logs in target/surefire-reports/ for individual tests that have failed leads me to this:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session ID may not be null.
```

While the test execution was going on, i noticed that the browser (firefox in my case) was trying to open but quitting in a second. Selenium server logs that there is no session id. It tries for a couple of times and quits trying. After which all other tests in the pipeline fail due to the same reason.

What's baffling is the fact that when i try to run these tests individually, this problem does not occur but when i'm trying to run all of them together using maven, this happens consistently. Help please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but I couldn't get selenium working via maven with any version of firefox beyond 3.x (from memory I used 3.18). I got your symptoms when using a later versions.

I tried everything, but conceded defeat and simply installed and lived with the older version.

At least our selenium tests worked and we got on with doing real work.

Comment: Interesting. I can get it to work on Firefox 11 no problem. Though i just figured that the tests fail the same way in Eclipse as they fail in maven. So doesn't really have to do with maven as expected.

Comment: My bad. I was just not invoking the browser correctly in my code. Just learnt a huge lesson on the keyword "static" in java. My code now works for FF 11.0 with selenium-server-2.20 and maven 2.2.1. Thanks for the response though. Let me know if you need help getting it to work Bohemian.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but usually when I see things failing when I run a group of tests, and passing when I run a single test, the culprits are usually either:

1) threading problem.  Are these tests multi-threaded?  If so, maybe there is some kind of resource contention.

2) tearDown problem.  Is there something happening in tearDown which is leaving the browser in a bad state such that the new browser can't start up cleanly?

Sorry I couldn't be of more help, I don't use Maven and Eclipse to drive my Selenium tests.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in this code of mine.

```
        WebDriver augmentedDriver;
        if(BrowserConfig.getHubURL().equalsIgnoreCase("none"))
            augmentedDriver = getDriver();
        else augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(getDriver());

        LOGGER.info("Just before capture: ");
        LOGGER.info(augmentedDriver.toString());
        byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
```

Figured out that driver.quit() was being called in o flow before the getscreenshot call. This b